# What is the distribution of the partition sizes of a randomly partitioned tuple?

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, summation, multinomial-distribution

Three equivalent formulations of my problem:

1. Suppose we have a tuple of size $n$ and partition it into $m$ parts so that the $m-1$ partition points are uniformly distributed over all possible partitions. What is the distribution of the cardinality of any of the partitions?
2. Suppose we are given $m$ identically independently distributed (by condition positive) Poisson random variables $X_i\in\mathbb N_+$ given $\sum_i^m X_i = n$. What is the distribution of $X_i$?
3. Suppose we toss a coin $n$ times and are given that `Heads` occurs exactly $m-1$ times. What is the distribution of the number of coin tosses until the first head is tossed?

I know that the joint distribution of the $X_i$ follows a multinomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p_i=\frac{1}{m}$. Consequently,

$$\Pr(X_i = k)= \sum_{k+k_2+\dots+k_m=n,\; k_i\geq 1}\frac{1}{m^n}{{n}\choose{k,k_2,\dots,k_{m}}}
$$

However, as I am interested in the distribution of only one $X_i$, I am wondering if there is a nice closed form solution for this nasty sum?

**Edit**

I am not sure if the multinomial distribution is actually appropriate, because the compartments follow a strict ordering. That is, an element at the end of the tuple is less likely to be in the first compartment than in the last.

Comment: You can get displayed equations by enclosing them in double instead of single dollar signs. This is particularly relevant for legibility if you mix fractions, exponents, subscripts and sum limits.

Comment: The question requires some clarification. The clearest formulation is the third. In this formulation, the random variable cannot take the value $0$. In the first formulation, you don't specify the full distribution of the partition points, but we can assume that you intended to imply that they are independent. If so, the length of a partition can be $0$, so this can't be equivalent to the third formulation. In the second formulation, you need to say more about the random variables $X_i$: are they uniform, discrete/continuous, what is their range?

Comment: @joriki Thank you for the comment. I have added further clarification. I think the problem with Xi≥1 can be transformed to the problem with permissible zeros via an index shift. Admitting zeros may make things a little easier.

Comment: This is still not entirely clear. By "the partition points are uniformly distributed (without repititions)", I presume you mean that the joint distribution of the partition points is uniform over all possible tuples of partition points without repetitions? And in the second formulation, you've now specified that the random variables are discrete, but still no joint or marginal distribution is specified for them. Are you implying that you believe that conditioning on the sum being $n$ makes the conditional distribution independent of the form of the unconditional distribution?

Comment: Thank you again @joriki for this excellent comment. Yes, I mean uniformly distributed over all partitions and yes, I falsely believed that the conditioning on the sum would make the distribution of the $X_i$ irrelevant. I am going to edit the question.

Comment: The second version is still not equivalent with the others. First, you still haven't specified that the $X_i$ are independent, and I doubt you'll get the equivalence you want without that. More specifically, though, if they are independent Poisson variables, that still doesn't imply that conditioning on their sum makes them uniform. This also requires their rate parameters to be equal.

Comment: @joriki Yes, I should specify they are independent before conditioning. However, that their rate is equal is given (I claimed they are identically ditributed).

Comment: Right – my bad.